# Open file instead of open changes by default in source control window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the default behavior in VSCode so that when I'm in the Source control window and I click on a file in the left pane, the file opens in the right pane instead of the changes window?  I see that if I right click a file I can choose to open it instead of the changes window but I'm lazy and just want to click once.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There is an icon which will let you open file itself without needing to right click:
[image]

It is also possible to change default behavior when left-clicking on the file name [since version 1.30](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_change-default-click-action):

To change it, set in your `settings.json`:

```
"git.openDiffOnClick": false
```

If you set it, the logic will inverse. Now, clicking on a file name will open the file, and clicking on the "inline icon" will open the diff.

It is also possible to disable this inline icon completely with:

```
"git.showInlineOpenFileAction": false
```

Comment: Is it possible to Open FIle from source control like Ctrl-clicking on it or so while still openning Diff on simple click? Or maybe set a shortcut for it like Ctrl+Shift+G + Ctrl+O?

Comment: @kolyaseg would be indeed best option

Comment: @kolyaseg It's possible to create a key binding to open the file from the diff. To add the shortcut, go to Cog > Keyboard Shortcuts and filter on `git.openFile`. Alternatively, you can manually add something like this to `keybindings.json`: `[ { "key": "alt+z", "command": "git.openFile" } ]`. The other way around (from regular view to diff view) is also possible using `git.openChange`.