# How to show "Open changes" icon in visual studio code

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-code

On the left, you see the icon I want to add on the VScode on the right.
[image]

The icon on the left is "Open changes" and the icon on the right VScode is "Open file"
How to add this icon? Does it need an extension or is it a setting?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693580/15250012

Answer (score 2):

Changing the following setting on settings.json:

`"git.openDiffOnClick": false` -> Open file icon is present.
`"git.openDiffOnClick": true` -> Open changes icon is present. (Default)